# Will strstr return the same pointer as the first string if the second string is at the beginning?

Tags: c, string, substring, c-strings, strstr

So basically, I need to find out if a string begins with `[URL]` and ends with `[/URL]`.

Right now I'm doing:

```
const char *urlStart;
// ...
urlStart = strstr(message, "[URL]");
if (urlStart == NULL) {
    urlStart = strstr(message, "[url]");
}

if (urlStart == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
```

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/), "a pointer to the first occurrence in str1 of the entire sequence of characters specified in str2".

Does that mean I can just do this?

```
/*
 * If the pointer to message is the same as urlStart,
 * message begins with urlStart
 */
if (message != urlStart) {
    return NULL;
}

// URL starts 5 characters after [URL]
urlStart += 5;
```

Initial testing seems to indicate that this doesn't work.

The complete function is located [here](https://github.com/NobleUplift/TeamSpeak3WebsitePreview/blob/master/ts3websitepreview/plugin.c#L247).

Comment: `NULL` + 5 is never equal to `NULL`. In other words, you need to check the return value from `strstr` before you go and do math on it.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for pointing that out! Originally my code was `strstr(message, "http://")` so I had no need for incrementing the pointer by 5 characters.

Comment: Yeah, now the code works. Think this question is worth keeping @user3386109?

Comment: I just undeleted the question @user3386109. I might switch user accounts soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the check `if (message != urlStart)` will work as expected, assuming that `message` begins with either `[URL]` or `[url]`. However if, for example, `message` starts with `[Url]`, then `strstr` won't find the string because of case mismatch.

Given that you require the string to be at a known location in `message`, the `strstr` function really doesn't do much for you. It's simpler just to check the first 5 characters of `message`, like this

```
char *start = "[URL]";
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    if ( toupper(message[i]) != start[i] )
        return NULL;
```

And you can check the `[/URL]` at the end like this

```
length = strlen(message);
if ( length < 12 )
    return NULL;

char *end = "[/URL]";
for ( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
    if ( toupper(message[length-6+i]) != end[i] )
        return NULL;
```

You could also use the non-case-sensitive-length-limited string compares, but note that those aren't portable. I believe it's `strnicmp` on Windows, and `strncasecmp` on unix clones.